# Clicking sound when playing a WAV file

Tags: wpf, windows, media-player

I'm writing an application that plays various WAV files. I'm using [`MediaPlayer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer(v=vs.110).aspx) class to play the sounds.

When raising the volume there's a distinct clicking sound at the beginning of each WAV file, and sometimes a click at the end. This *also* happens when playing the files in Windows Groove or VLC Player. Playing the same files in Audacity works perfectly - there's no clicking sound. The click is also not found in the WAV itself (I know this by looking at the sound wave in Audacity).

So obviously there's another, probably more lowlevel way, of playing WAV files. How can I play them without these clicks?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was with a too-loud sample. The volume in the sample was maximal. Once I reduced the sample volume (multiplying each value by 0.6 actually), the clicking sound disappeared - even when I turned up the speaker volume. Way up.